# How to avoid error `cannot remove 'XXXXX': is a directory`

Tags: bash

I'm new in BASH and I'm trying to make a simple script.
I would like to run the script from a different directory, and then the script should delete all my files in my current directory. (ONLY FILES)
So the function is:

```
eraseAllFiles()
{   
    rm * 
    echo "Files deleted!"
    sleep 1.3
}
```

So the command `rm *` delete all my files but then I get this error:

`cannot remove 'XXXXX': is a directory`.

My question is how can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `rm` use `find -type f` to delete only files:

```
eraseAllFiles() {   
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete 
    echo "Files deleted!"
    sleep 1.3
}
```

Comment: `-delete` isn't supported by all versions of `find`; the standard way is `-exec rm {} +`.

Comment: Yes that's right non non-gnu platforms `-exec rm {} +` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
eraseAllFiles()
{   
    rm * 2>/dev/null
    echo "Files deleted!"
    sleep 1.3
}
```

The `2>/dev/null` part sends the standard error output to `/dev/null` which effectively means that it's not displayed.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to delete both files and directory use

```
rm -r *
```